# Is there any way to convert UWP App into windows Desktop WPF Application

Tags: wpf, uwp, desktop-application

We know that Desktop application can be converted into UWP apps.
But I want to Convert My UWP App into Desktop WPF Applictaion.
How to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple way how to achieve that. Even the conversion from desktop app to UWP app is not really a conversion - it just packs the desktop app in an APPX package so it can be published to Windows Store.

The only way is to rewrite your code.